# Loop through multiple models in MVC 5 using razor

Tags: razor, foreach, model, viewdata, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm setting a `ViewData.Model` that gets populated from a a data table. In my View, I'm looping through the `ViewData.Model` displaying the data. I'm trying to create a **second** `ViewData.Model` and do the same thing. How do I accomplish this? I have the code to the first ViewData.Model that is working. If you keep looking below, I have my attempt at setting the second `ViewData.Model` but I'm unable to display the data in the view...

**Controller with working ViewData.Model**

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);
ViewData.Model = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
```

**View with working ViewData.Model**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
{
   @item["ACCT_ID"]
}
```

**Controller with second ViewData.Model**

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(dataReader);
ViewData["scheduledDate"] = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
```

**View pulling with second ViewData.Model but doesn't work**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["scheduledDate"] )
{
    @item["DATE_ID"]
}
```

**Update - Working second ViewData.Model**
Thanks to @teo van kot , i'm now able to display content with my 2nd ViewData.Model. Here is the code in my view that works...

```
 @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>)ViewData["scheduledDate"])
    {
        @item["DATE_ID"]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast your model to your Type if you using `ViewData`.

Like this:

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<YourType>)ViewData["scheduledDate"] )
{
    @item["DATE_ID"]
}
```

Only change `YourType` to type that you actually have and this will work

Comment: Thanks for the post. I think i'm getting closer, but I have to ask a dumb question. How do I determine what type I actually have? I tried using  `IEnumerable<string>`, but then `@item["DATE_ID"]` complains saying "cannot convert string from int". I then tried `IEnumerable<int>` and still got errors

Comment: @GRU119 set break point in your controller and then chek in watch instrument what do you really have there

Comment: You are the man! It turns out the type I needed was `System.Data.DataRow`